# Delete a folder if a sub-sub-folder within it has files older than 30 days

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, path, forfiles

I have the following path : C:\folder\subfolder1\subfolder2

I would like to check if all files within "subfolder2" are over 30 days old and if so delete C:\folder path (not only subfolder2).

Using forfiles I can delete subfolder2 but not delete up to parent folder (C:\folder) :

```
@echo off
forfiles.exe /s /d -30 /p "C:\folder" /c "cmd.exe /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /s /q @path"
exit
```

Do you have any idea how to do this ?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I must assume that any content of `C:\folder\subfolder1` is irrelevant then! Also I would advise that the first thing you should do is to define for sure your current working directory in the batch file itself. You need to ensure that the current working directory is certainly not part of the potentially deleted directory structure, i.e. in this case `C:\folder` or any of its directories or subdirectories. The safest way would be to make it the root directory, ```C:\```. You cannot remove a directory which is also the current working directory. Do you know the name of the target directory?

Comment: There is no relevant content in C:\folder\ and C:\subfolder1 other than this subfdolder2.

Comment: **C:\folder\subfolder1

Comment: The target directory is something like Z:\logs\computername\username

Comment: I don't need to know them, what I'm asking is do you know their actual names prior to running the code i.e. is it always `folder`, _(`logs`?)_, `subfolder1`, _(`computername`?)_, and `subfolder2`, _(`username`)_? I'm tyying to ascertain whether its a simple case of using `/P` with `C:\folder\subfolder1\subfolder2`, _(`Z:\logs\computername\username`)_, no recursion, and  then you'd know the full path of the' to remove' directory, `C:\folder`, _(`Z:\logs`)_.

Comment: I's always logs\computername\username (but computername and username may have a different name depending on the name of the PC and the user). The problem with forfiles is that it deletes the parent folder if it contains a subfolder and then files less than 30 days old. What I would like is that it could first check if there are any files less than 30 days old in the username subfolder, and if so, not delete anything. Otherwise delete the username subfolder, and the parent computername folder

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `/S` option but let `forfiles` only process the sub-sub-folder, then delete the top-level folder in case all found files are at least 30 days old (meaning they have been last modified 30 days ago or earlier):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=U:\TEST\top" & rem // (full path to top-level directory)
set "_LEV1=*"           & rem // (name or mask of sub-directory)
set "_LEV2=*"           & rem // (name or mask of sub-sub-directory)
set "_MASK=*"           & rem // (mask for files in sub-sub-directory)
set /A "_AGE=30"        & rem // (age in number of days of the files)

rem // Initialise counter for files that are newer than the given age:
set /A "SUM=0"
rem // Iterate through all matching sub-directories of the top-level directory:
for /D %%A in ("%_ROOT%\%_LEV1%") do (
    rem // Iterate through all matching sub-sub-directories of the current sub-directory:
    for /D %%B in ("%%~A\%_LEV2%") do (
        rem // Initialise an auxiliary flag that indicates whether the following loop iterates the second time:
        set "FLAG="
        rem /* In the following `for /F` loop two `forfiles` command lines are executed in order to retrieve the
        rem    number of matching files in the current sub-sub-directory that are newer than the given age;
        rem    since `forfiles` cannot return files newer than a given age (since `/D +` points to the future!),
        rem    let us determine the diffenence between the numbers of all files and such older than the given age;
        rem    the condition `if @isdir==FALSE` is intentionally omitted in the first `forfiles` command line,
        rem    because otherwise, sub-directories od the current sub-sub-directory would then become lost: */
        for /F %%C in ('
            rem/ /* Determine numbers of all files minus aged out files: */ ^& ^
                2^> nul forfiles /P "%%~B" /M "%_MASK%" /C "cmd /C echo #" ^| find /C "#" ^& ^
                2^> nul forfiles /P "%%~B" /M "%_MASK%" /D -%_AGE% /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE echo #" ^| find /C "#"
        ') do (
            rem /* The flag is not defined in the first iteration when all files are counted, but is is defined in
            rem    the second iteration when newer files are filtered out and the older ones are counted: */
            if defined FLAG (set /A "SUM-=%%C") else set /A "SUM+=%%C" & set "FLAG=#"
        )
    )
    rem // The following line is merely intended for debugging purposes and may be removed:
    >&2 (for /F %%D in ('set /A "SUM"') do echo Processing "%%~nxA\%%~nxB": found %%D newer file^(s^) so far...)
)
rem // The following line does actually not delete anything unless you remove the upper-case `ECHO` statement:
if %SUM% equ 0 ECHO rd /S /Q "%_ROOT%"

endlocal
exit /B
```